# Strange Python import behaviour

Tags: python, package, python-import

I have a problem with importing sub-packages. The packages structure I have is:

```
project/
    __init__.py
    defaults.py
    helpers/
       __init__.py
       misc.py
```

I need to use data from `defaults.py` all over the project, including `helpers\misc.py`, while in `defaults.py` I need to use some functions from `helpers\misc.py`. To solve the circular reference I'm trying to refer everything from project root, i.e. inside `defaults.py` I do

```
import project

project.helpers.somefunction()
```

However this doesn't work. It does work though when I import the function directly, like this:

```
from project.helpers import somefunction

somefunction()
```

But then I have a circular reference problem.
I also have same problem everywhere inside the project subpackages, but in other places I can import subpackages directly and workaround the problem.

So, why it works if I import from subpackages, but doesn't when I refer to same subpackages starting from the root package?

*PS: there are no files like `helpers.py` on the same level with `helpers\` or inside it.*

*PPS: whole project package is added to `sys.path` via `sys.path.insert(0, '<project_abs_path>')`*

*PPPS: Python 2.7.3, Ubuntu 12.04*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import project.helpers

project.helpers.somefunction()
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this helps?

Comment: @Ophion when you import a package this **executes** the code in `__init__.py`. Period. It does **not** import subpackages. If you want to automatically import subpackages then you have to do so in the `__init__.py` of the package. A package is just like any other module. The only difference is its layout in the file-system(using `name/__init__.py` instead of `name.py`) and the ability to do relative imports.